# Javascript text effects work on Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firefox seems to be able to show animations correctly: https://i.imgur.com/bh8Mz8J.mp4

but Chrome doesn't seem to show them correctly, and it also doesn't show the `<span>` with a gradient background like it does with "hello", but the `span` text is there:
https://i.imgur.com/r11zC0q.mp4

This is the Javascript code I'm using from [Tobias Ahlin](https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/)

```
function welcome()
        {
            var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml3');
            textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

            anime.timeline()
                .add({
                    targets: '.ml3 .letter',
                    opacity: [0,1],
                    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
                    duration: 750,
                    delay: (el, i) => 100 * (i+1)
                });
        }
```

As well as the CSS for the gradient background

```
.gradient-text-1 {
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #4dacfa 0%, #c0e994 100%);
}
```

This is the HTML code that I'm currently using, where `.ml3` just styles the text with the cursive font and is also used as a target in the Javascript code.

```
<div class="jumbotron w-75 mx-auto text-center">
    <h1 class="ml3 gradient-text-1">hello</h1>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to make the animations on Chrome the same as Firefox, as that was what I was intending to go for. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow ! Can you include an example of HTML needed to test this ? (your HTML)

Comment: Hi! I've edited the post with the HTML I'm using. I have a feeling this boils down to how Chrome and Firefox renders the gradient background in the ```span```.

Comment: Does it works for you ? https://codepen.io/zedentox/pen/MWJRZzQ
Also the gradient is ok but "hello" is a little bit too short to see the effect.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've given up on this implementation, instead I let the text render as `text-fill-color: inherit` first, and then when the Javascript animation is complete I run a CSS animation to `text-fill-color: transparent`. Different style but it mostly accomplishes what I want. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to provide test cases. Your style code should be written as follows:

```
.gradient-text-1 {
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #4dacfa 0%, #c0e994 100%);
}
```